# BufferedWriter to ProcessBuilder input?

Tags: java, io, bufferedwriter

I've tried lots of different options, but nothing seems to work. I can't get my code to output a string to the "console" of a process. Here's my code:

```
    Process p;
    // Create new ProcessBuilder
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "jar-location").inheritIO();
    // Change work directory
    pb.directory(new File("other-location"));
    // Redirect output
    pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\log.json"));
    // Start ProcessBuilder
    p = pb.start();
    OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
    while(!done) {
        try {
            if(go != null) {
                writer.write(formatted[0])
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        }
    }
```

"p" is the process that I'm trying to submit input to and "formatted" is an array of data. When you run this, nothing happens. I've tried flushing/closing the writer, but I can't get it in a spot without getting "java IO Exception: Stream Closed". Can anyone tell what's wrong with my code?

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:316)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:266)
    at com.Rocket_Scientist.Main.main(Main.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Also, what is `client`?

Comment: I attached the stacktrace from when it crashes from writer.close(). Client is is just a source of data for Formatted, I probably could've removed it from the snippet.

Comment: That `ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream` is telling.  Edit your question and show the code which creates the ProcessBuilder.  From ProcessBuilder’s documentation: “a source of *standard input.* By default, the subprocess reads input from a pipe. Java code can access this pipe via the output stream returned by `Process.getOutputStream()`. However, standard input may be redirected to another source using `redirectInput`. In this case, `Process.getOutputStream()` will return a *null output stream,* for which: the write methods always throw IOException; the close method does nothing.”

Comment: Ok, I've added the ProcessBuilder part.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem, thanks to [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) (thanks!). The ".inheritIO()" was redirecting the output stream, causing the problem.
Thanks!